# Visual Studio 2012- Connection to local db (error 26)

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

super new to Visual Studios and i need some help with regards to connection to database.
I only have visual studios 2012 installed. 
So I'm trying to create a simple sign up form, and storing the information into a table(created a local database for this with the table 'Users'.)

The problem is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or is not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server name is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified.)

Er, so what should I do?  :(

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    Try

        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf;"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con

        Dim sha1 As SHA1 = sha1.Create()
        Dim password As Byte() = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password1.Text))

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES('" & username1.Text & "','" & password1.Text & "');"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error :  " & ex.Message, "insert data")

    Finally

        con.Close()
    End Try
```

Thanks guys.

**EDIT:**
Sad to say , I dont have any SQLExpress here in my laptop. so Yeahhh.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen due to the SQLExpress has been stopped...Try to start it manually by going to services

Comment: Thanks for replying Coder, but sad to say , I dont have any SQLExpress here in my laptop . so yeahhhhhh . :/ how should i go about it.

Comment: Then without installing it how are you expecting to run this code ? For that reason it is throwing the exception..Try to install sql management studio from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Comment: HAHAHAH! i dont know it's a must to install this. Opps! Thanks Coder. I'll go try out.